# What is the best way to create one per time session? (ASP.NET, MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

What is the best way to create one per time session? For example, if user logged from one IP and browser should not login from other place in one moment. Maybe there are exists some standard solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Since the web uses a disconnected model, there is no foolproof way to determine if a user is truly online. Using the standard ASP.NET membership, you could use the [IsOnline property of the MembershipUser object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.isonline.aspx), and prevent the user from logging in if the value is `true`. However, you will have to determine, perhaps by IP address, if the incoming request is from a second user at a different location, or the same user that had a session timeout but still has `IsOnline == true`.

You will probably have to put up with a certain amount of false positives, if you take this approach.

Comment: what will be the action if i closed my browser without logout?

Comment: The server has no way to know that. Your session will remain active until the timeout is reached, then the session is discarded.

Comment: so up to my session will expire.  I will not able to login again in system?

Comment: You can probably get around that limitation, but you will have to write code to try and detect that it is the same user logging in from the same location.